# How can we describe the difference for these instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

```
movl $0x7, %eax
movl $0x7, (%eax)

movl 0x7, (%eax)
```

In my opinion it would be mov the long value to eax register.
second line is move the long value to the memory of eax register.

What does the third line do ?

I am little confused about these.

Comment: yup, mov-immediate to register vs. mov-immediate to memory, with a simple addressing mode using just EAX as the address.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov

Comment: *What does the third line do ?* - fails to assemble.  Did you try it?  x86 doesn't allow an instruction with two memory operands, and `0x7` is a memory operand with absolute address `7`.  See [Why isn't movl from memory to memory allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33794169) and [Does referencing constants without a dollar sign have a distinct meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42727668)

Comment: I didnt try it, but i am new to x86 and found this code somwhere asking, what does this line mean ? I got confused and thats why asked here.

Comment: You should try to figure out as much as you can before you ask other people to spend their time explaining things to you.  e.g. find a tutorial and docs (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info / https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info), and/or look at compiler output to see what instructions a compiler uses for C you already understand.  ([How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)).  And play around with it yourself, putting instructions in a file so you can single-step them in GDB and see what happens.